# Group by and count with inner join

Tags: sql

I have a table with orders and a table with material (1:N).
I want to know how many orders have screens in the material table for a certain production order and country.

The query at the bottom gives me the quantity of screens per order for each order instead of the expected result 5:

```
6
1 
6
2
2 

SELECT Count(ORD.ORDERNUMMER)
FROM        Orders AS ORD
INNER JOIN Material AS KP ON KP.Ordernummer = ORD.Ordernummer
WHERE (KP.SOORT = 'SCREEN') AND ORD.PRODUCTIEORDER = '201132' AND ORD.LAND = 'Belgie'
Group By ORD.Ordernummer HAVING (COUNT(*) >= 1)
```

I just want to have 5 returned.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count each distinct order, if it has at least one line of material which is screen.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT ORD.ORDERNUMMER)
FROM        Orders AS ORD
INNER JOIN Material AS KP ON KP.Ordernummer = ORD.Ordernummer
WHERE (KP.SOORT = 'SCREEN') AND ORD.PRODUCTIEORDER = '201132' AND ORD.LAND = 'Belgie'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't group the results if you need the whole total!

```
SELECT Count(ORD.ORDERNUMMER) as totalScreens
FROM Orders AS ORD
INNER JOIN Material AS KP ON KP.Ordernummer = ORD.Ordernummer
WHERE (KP.SOORT = 'SCREEN') AND ORD.PRODUCTIEORDER = '201132' AND ORD.LAND = 'Belgie'
HAVING (totalScreens >= 1)
```

Comment: Removing the group by without COUNT(DISTINCT) will return 17 instead of 5

Comment: Are you really sure? we are not talking about `SUM()`

Comment: If you see the results there are 5 orders, and the number's are the count of each order's lines which product is screen

Comment: Did you check my answer? There is no group by, but removing it is not enough, right?

Comment: If there are more than one row in the materials table then you will double count the order because of the join. Distinct will count each order once.